# what is "Updating a Solr Index"

Tags: solr

I read http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages , but i did not get what does it mean by updating solr index. does it mean that we can update index via query??
it means we can add or delete a doc for which we do not have/have data in database, but we can have index for that.

Answer (score 1):

> what does it mean by updating solr index.

It means you can add, update and delete documents from the Solr index. If you couldn't do this Solr would be pretty useless...

> does it mean that we can update index via query??

No, queries are safe, readonly operations. They never change the index.

> it means we can add or delete a doc for which we do not have/have data in database, but we can have index for that

Adding or deleting documents in Solr has nothing to do with records in your database. Solr is in principle independent of relational databases. It doesn't really care where data comes from or whether the data in the index matches the data you have in your database.